# Fetching S3 object Nifi

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I want to fetch one particular file from S3, only once. So I used listS3 and FetchS3object processors. But whenever I start the listS3 processor and stop it after 1 second, by that time it generates thousands of flowfiles and when these flowfiles are passed to FetchS3object processor, the same file is fetched thousands of time.
I even changed the scheduling time in listS3 processor, but still, the same effect exists.
Could someone tell me where I was going wrong with the configurations?